# Some octal-coded symbol characters can't work in gnuplot labeling

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, symbols, eps, octal

I wanted to use the symbol of "\times" (we use in TeX) in gnuplot(5.0 in windows 8.1) labeling, and wrote the script including the following:

```
set term post eps enh
set xl 'a{/Symbol \264}b'
```

\264 is the octal code of "\times", that I referred to [ps_guide.pdf](http://materials.ucsd.edu/doc/ps_guide.pdf).

However, the font specification by /Symbol didn't work on \264, and "\cdot" like character was output instead of "\times". I also tried {/Symbol a} and {/Symbol \141}, and confirmed both output "\alpha" correctly. It seems that the octal codes greater than 220 can't find the corresponding /Symbol characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly you code works fine for me with gnuplot 5.0 on Windows 8.1 (Used gsview as viewer): http://i.stack.imgur.com/VdDb9.png

Comment: Same here, it works fine with gnuplot 4.6.5 on linux (Suse 13.2)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your case, Christoph. It was very suggestive that you succeeded viewing using gsview. I previously used Adobe Illustrator for viewing, however, looking into the content of the eps file, I found the description "[(Arial)...(a)][(Symbol)...(\264)][(Arial)...(b)]" (partly omitted).So, it's surely working! Now I got a correct "\times" readable in AI by converting the file using eps2pdf. Thanks a lot! Also thanks to sweber!

Comment: Anyway, I don't know why Adobe Illustrtor(cc 18.1.1) can't render the symbol font greater than a certain octal number...

Comment: @rummymummy _I don't know why Adobe Illustrator..._ ... that's another question maybe for SuperUser site..  It's probably a problem of the used font limited to that number...